# NSDictionary initialization results in "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: objective-c, ios

I can not figure out why this code is bad. I thought it was ok to use static strings in dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys however it fails at runtime with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I used the debugger to identify that it is in fact failing at the definition line. It never outputs "Made it here".

```
- (NSString *)polyName:(NSUInteger)vertices { 
    NSLog(@"looking for polyName with %d vertices.", vertices);

    NSDictionary *polNameDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"triangle", @"3", 
                             @"square", @"4",
                             @"pentagon","5",
                             @"Hexagon", @"6",
                             @"Heptagon", @"7",
                             @"Octagon", @"8",
                             @"Nonagon", @"9",
                             @"Decagon", @"10",
                             @"Hendecagon", @"11",
                             @"Dodecagon", @"12",
                             nil];

   NSLog(@"Made it here");

   NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", vertices]; 
   NSString *polName = [polNameDict objectForKey:key];
   return (polName);
   // Memory management: No need to release polNameDict, key, polName because they use
   // convenience functions
}
```

Comment: First fix `@"pentagon","5"` to `@"pentagon", @"5"`.

Comment: @Anna - should post that as an answer, as it seems that is actually the issue

Comment: Anna I love you. OMG, I wasted a good hour on that. ARRRGGH. Silly typo. Thank you. This community rocks btw.

Comment: @Anna, agreed, that was the issue, I can make a check for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@"pentagon","5"
```

It expects an object (NSString) but instead there's a regular string.
Change it to:

```
@"pentagon", @"5"
```

Answer (score -4):

What line does the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occur on? Utilize breakpoints and let us know.

For now, if I were you, I'd do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *polNameDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"triangle", @"3", 
                             @"square", @"4",
                             @"pentagon",@"5",
                             @"Hexagon", @"6",
                             @"Heptagon", @"7",
                             @"Octagon", @"8",
                             @"Nonagon", @"9",
                             @"Decagon", @"10",
                             @"Hendecagon", @"11",
                             @"Dodecagon", @"12",
                             nil];
```

instead of how you have it now.

Comment: Tx. I did use the debugger to find it was failing on the initWithObjectsAndKeys line. I will swap to alloc and see what happens.

Comment: -1 This is just black magic debugging. Replacing the `-dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` with alloc/init won't make a difference -- either style is perfectly valid.

Comment: I added some NSLog statement to show if it ever makes it past the initialization. It doesn't. I tried the alloc code you have. It is still failing on the initialization line.

Comment: @vesselhead, did you see Anna's comment to your question? She's got the right answer.

Comment: Yes Caleb, tx. I had already messed with the alloc as well. But it was worth the retry. Tx again everyone.